# ERROR: Not enough space?

Tags: solaris, oracle, disk-space-utilization

Now this is a very unspecific question. I'm trying to figure out what this message would mean.

Here is the story behind it:
I'm installing Oracle enterprise manager cloud control (12c r3) on Solaris 10 (5/09). Installer opens up, i enter all needed information and at the last step click Install. It immediately crashes with only "ERROR: Not enough space" written in log and console and nothing else.

Now, this could be java error or Solaris error? I'm thinking it's happening either when it starts to copy files or when it tries to launch a process that would do that.

What space is it referring to? disk (have ehough), swap (also), memory (yep)...

Any ideas are helpful.

Edit:
i found this exception in the oraInventory logs:

```
oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPIException: Not enough space
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAPIInstaller.initInstallSession(OiicAPIInstaller.java:2165)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAPIInstaller.initOUIAPISession(OiicAPIInstaller.java:790)
    at oracle.sysman.install.oneclick.EMGCOUIInstaller.prepareForInstall(EMGCOUIInstaller.java:676)
    at oracle.sysman.install.oneclick.EMGCSummaryDlgonNext$1.run(EMGCSummaryDlgonNext.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at oracle.sysman.install.oneclick.EMGCSummaryDlgonNext.actionsOnClickofNext(EMGCSummaryDlgonNext.java:1067)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at oracle.sysman.install.oneclick.EMGCUtil.performonClickOfNextForClass(EMGCUtil.java:399)
    at oracle.sysman.install.oneclick.EMGCUtil.performPageLevelValidationsForSilentInstall(EMGCUtil.java:367)
    at oracle.sysman.install.oneclick.EMGCInstaller.prepareForSilentInstall(EMGCInstaller.java:1459)
    at oracle.sysman.install.oneclick.EMGCInstaller.main(EMGCInstaller.java:1553)
```

disk status:

```
bash-3.00$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
swap                   8.1G   2.7G   5.4G    33%    /tmp

bash-3.00$ df -h /u01
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/                      275G    28G   244G    11%    /
```

swap:

```
root@gs12emcc # swap -s
total: 18306040k bytes allocated + 3837808k reserved = 22143848k used, 5712664k available
```

Comment: Check permissions. It's a common problem that programs report storage space problems when in reality they lack permissions for whatever operation they try.

Comment: I checked, all seems ok. I'm not sure if i'm missing something solaris specific. Also, i managed to install database software without problems... same user, same base dir

Comment: I found the exception, but still no luck with what causes it.

Comment: show us the output of du and df -sh for the relevant disks. Also you presumably have a valid Oracle support contract - call them too.

Comment: updated disk spaces. 
as for support, i guess i will have to do that eventually. thought to get an quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that Solaris was missing latest patch set and was not certified in this combination. Switching to Solaris 11 or 10 with latest update fixed the problem.